# Validation of HTML table cell and changing background color using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

This is HTML table and I want to validate it in such a way that if user clears entry, the background color of particular cell should be turned red. Code for model should be in JavaScript or Typescript. Please don't provide jQuery solutions

**app.component.html**

```
  <table class="material-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <!-- <th *ngFor="let schema of tableSchema">
          {{ schema.field }}
        </th> -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let rowData of tableData">
      <td value="Delete" (click)="deleteRow(rowData)">X</td>
      <td
        *ngFor="let schema of tableSchema"
        [class.red-text]="!rowData[schema.field].valid"
      >
        <span
          #el
          contenteditable
          (blur)="rowData[schema.field].value = el.innerText"
          
        >
          {{ rowData[schema.field].value }}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried ngClass?

Comment: No, I know how to validate form elements and individual elements of static table fields but Main problem is I have never applied validation when table is displayed in loops (using ng for)

Comment: So you just want the class to be applied if this condition satisfies, `!rowData[schema.field].valid`?

Comment: Yes, you got it correct

Comment: Please use the correct tags. AngularJS (https://angularjs.org) is a different framework from Angular (https://angular.io). When typing the tags in the Tags box on desktop, it should show "tag excerpts"; bits of information about the tag you are about to add to your question; please be sure to read those when present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

```
<td *ngFor="let schema of tableSchema" [ngClass]="{'red-text':!rowData[schema.field].valid}">
    <span #el contenteditable (blur)="rowData[schema.field].value = el.innerText">
        {{ rowData[schema.field].value }}
    </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Attribute directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives):

**JS**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, KeyValueDiffers } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[requiredHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  color = "red";

  @HostListener('input') onChange() {
    this.highlight();
  }

  private highlight() {
    const color = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML ? null: this.color;
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

**HTML Template:**

```
<td *ngFor="let schema of tableSchema">
   <span #el contenteditable requiredHighlight (blur)="rowData[schema.field].value = el.innerText" >
      {{ rowData[schema.field].value }}
   </span>
 </td>
```

Comment: I like this solution because it can be reused in other templates.